# Exchange 2013 Mailbox Step 10

Tags: exchange-2013

please i have this error message when installing exchange 2013 on windows server 2012 R2 on the step 10 of 14 Mailbox

the following error was generated when $error.clear()

start-Setupservice-ServiceName MSExchangeSubmission

"was run: "Service ' MSExchangeSubssimin ' failed to reach status Running on this server "

[image]

Comment: Can you give anymore information? A screenshot perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

Which build of Exchange 2013 are you using?
The error means what it says - the service failed to start. There could be additional information in the Setup Logs.